# Why the intensity vs. frequency graph initially increases for black-body radiation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Max Planck had said that $E = n h \nu$ in his quantum theory. Then according to it, as the frequency of the light emitted increases, so the light's intensity should decrease. But it is not in the initial observation of graph. Why?

Comment: Do you have the graph, or the link to it?

Comment: This equation is _totally not_ about intensity.

Answer (score 2):

As Ivan Neretin mentioned in comments, there is no any "intensity" in $E = n h \nu$ formula. Besides, this was the original supposition Planck made with the final formula being (essentially) the following,
$$
  B_\nu(\nu, T)
  \sim
  \nu^3 \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\nu/T}-1} \, ,
$$
where $B_\nu$ is the *[spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance)* per unit frequency, which is basically the "intensity" OP is looking for. A [quick drawing](https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=x%5E3%20*%201%2F(e%5Ex%20-%201)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=0&x_max=15&y_min=0&y_max=2&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=1&y_label_freq=1&do_grid=0&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525) of $\nu$-dependence shows that the $B_\nu$ curve has the desired shape:

[image]

Details can be found, for instance, in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law).